# Ubuntu 18.04 Permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache2

I have multiple websites hosted on my server. The default user for apache is www-data.

For the different websites I have used different folders.
Use for example user gary.
When I try to write log files to gary unless I change the ownership of the log file directory (chown) to www-data (home/gary/public_html/logs), the files will not be written to.
I have tried

```
chown -R www-data:gary /home/gary/public_html/logs
```

with no luck. I have to use

```
chown -R www-data /home/gary/public_html/logs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the relevant Apache httpd configuration?

Comment: Also, I believe only the root user may own the logs. Should user `www-data` own the logs and have write permissions, an intruder can overwrite the logs and cover its tracks. The log files are opened by `httpd` as the root user. If I remember correctly, at least....

Comment: Maybe to clarify the log files i am writing are debug log files from within php using fopen,fwrite,fclose. I am not trying to access apache log files.

Comment: Since it is PHP’s log files, please share how it is setup. FastCGI, mod_php... the setup could influence which user the php processes are run as. Thus which permissions are needed on the files.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you want to do.

This command will try to change the owner of the folder and everything it containt to user "www-data" and group "gary"

```
chown -R www-data:gary /home/gary/public_html/logs
```

Is what you want to do ?

There could only have ONE owner at a time.

Please put the actual folder rights and reformulate what you want to do.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do, but even though gary is in the user group www-data I still cant make all the files in that directory home/gary/public_html owned by gary. If I do my error log files (from inside my php scripts) wont write. I have to make home/gary/public_html/logs owned by www-data

Comment: That's how it must be. I do not understand why you want the files of a website to belong to different users.
```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/gary/public_html/logs
```
If you want user gary acces to files, you have to add Gary in the group www-data and you will be fine